# How would I go about rfewriting a logical url such as /Survey/Survey1 to /Surveys.aspx?id=1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a simple survey app that has a url rewrite where I can I will pass in the surveyname in the url I would like to rewrite this to a query string.  Just looking for how to get started on this.  Should I use an httphandler or module?  Thanks!

Comment: Use one of the many UrlRewriting modules already existing.

Comment: Yeah, kinda wanted to learn it though since this is a personal project I have used them in the past when developement time matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own HttpModule and insert regex there